# Oracle SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY with SRID

Tags: sql, database, geometry, spatial, geo

I have this kind of sql query

```
create table TEST_GEOMS(
            ID VARCHAR2(30) not null,
            geometry SDO_GEOMETRY not null
        )

insert into TEST_GEOMS values (st_1, SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('LINESTRING (11.681684 48.239255, 11.681951 48.239216, 11.682218 48.239176)'))
```

After that the SRID is missing in the database table. How can I also pass the SRID?

Comment: did you solve the problem? was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [SDO_GEOMETRY Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-constructors.htm#SPATL501):

```
insert into TEST_GEOMS values (st_1, sdo_geometry(wkt, srid))
```